# Step by step guide to install SL4A in Android

Tags: android, sl4a

I know that there are many questions like this, but most of those answers are outdated or just does not work.

I have been trying to install SL4A and some interpreters like Rhino, Python.
Since the SL4A project was moved from Goggle servers to GitHub, I tried to search for SL4A in GitHub, but I cannot understand which are the right packages to download and how to install those. I have followed many different sites, but most of the contents are outdated and so, I am getting more and more confused.

I want step by step installation instructions for SL4A and all of it's interpreters. Hope that this question may help others too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... It's a pretty old project; not sure what you expect fine years after its last commit.

Comment: Really? Is the SL4A pretty old? Then are there any alternatives or replacements for it?